# How to get informed about any certificate changes

Tags: android, certificate, ssl-certificate

Android 4.0 allows user to manage certificates (enable, disable, install)... But is it possible to get notified about such changes? Is there some broadcast or anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jelly Bean (API level 16) has an [ACTION_STORAGE_CHANGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyChain.html#ACTION_STORAGE_CHANGED) broadcast. It doesn't give you details though (what happened and with witch certificate), the idea is that if you are caching certificates or trust status you should invalidate your cache and re-verify, etc. There is nothing on ICS though, AFAIK.